# I want to get what is written in the title from within the html table

Tags: javascript, html

here's my code:

```
 <td class="text-left"><div class="ettn" data-toggle="tooltip" title="7f5e5b03-7d30-4001-acd9-c993d6c24301">ETTN</div></td>
```

I want to get what is written in title instead of ETTN, (with loop). How can i do that?

[image]

Comment: Print where? Please provide more details.

Comment: So type it in the text instead of an attribute in the first place then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you would get and write the value of EETN title with javascript.

```js
eetn_divs = document.querySelectorAll(".eetn")

for (var i= 0, len = eetn_divs.length; i < len; i++) {
    value = eetn_divs[i].getAttribute('title');
    eetn_divs[i].innerText = value
}
```

Comment: @nihalhızal if it worked you should except the answer (by clicking the tick mark)!